# why is this function non exhaustive?

Tags: haskell

Compiler warns the function "insert" is non-exhaustive in the following code:

```
data Set a = Empty | Set a (Set a) (Set a) deriving (Eq, Show)

insert :: (Ord a) => a -> Set a -> Set a
insert x Empty = Set x Empty Empty
insert x (Set v l r)
  | x <= v = Set v (insert x l) r
  | v < x  = Set v l (insert x r)
--  | otherwise = Set x Empty Empty

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = insert (5::Int) Empty
  print x
```

GHC reports this

```
test.hs:4:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘insert’: Patterns not matched: _ (Set _ _ _)
```

If I uncomment the last line (it's commented out now) in the function, GHC does not report any warning. So I guess GHC thinks the guards are non-exhaustive. But why? If x and v are instances of Ord, then I guess 
(x <= v) and (v < x) are all the possible outcomes of comparison?

Comment: Haskell can't assume that `(<=)` and `(<)` are related like that. You can pattern match on the result of `compare` though.

Comment: The compiler is not so smart to check that no other case exists when you use guards. Also, if you are sure that the last guard will catch all the remaining cases, you should use `| otherwise = ...` which is more efficient (no comparison is needed) and tells the compiler that this will indeed catch all the cases.

Comment: Keep in mind that guards can be arbitrary boolean expressions, which means a guard could be `| x^75 + y^75 /= z^75` and then the compiler would have to be able to prove Fermat's Last Theorem in order to decide that this guard will always be true!

Comment: @chi, the most recent versions of GHC try pretty hard, but they definitely have their limits.

Comment: @dfeuer Really? GHC exhaustiveness checker now tries to handle non trivial guards? I thought it never looked inside guards but for trivial cases like `True, otherwise`

Comment: @chi, I do believe so. Lots of work happened.

Comment: Just FYI: what you call `Set` is typically called `Tree`.

Answer (score 7):

What if I define this instance:

```
newtype Fuzzy = Fuzzy Double
instance Eq Fuzzy where
  Fuzzy a == Fuzzy b = abs (a-b) < 0.1
instance Ord Fuzzy where
  Fuzzy a < Fuzzy b = a < b-0.1
  Fuzzy a <= Fuzzy b = a <= b
```

Then for e.g. `v = Fuzzy 0`, `x = Fuzzy 0.1`, you have `(x <= v) = (0.1 <= 0)` which is false, but `(v < x) = (0 < 0)` which is *also* false. Hence both of your guards will fail.

This isn't so hypothetical, in fact `Double` itself already [has such behaviour in degenerate values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN):

```
Prelude> sqrt (-1) < 0
False
Prelude> 0 <= sqrt (-1)
False
```

Now, it's very debatable whether these are really good, even well-formed `Ord` instances, but at any rate the compiler can't *guarantee* something like that won't happen. Hence it also can't make the assumption that `not (x <= v)` implies `v < x`, so *what should happen* if neither is fulfilled?

The usual thing to do if you assume all `Ord` instances you received are docile is to just make the second clause already catch-all:

```
insert x (Set v l r)
  | x <= v     = Set v (insert x l) r
  | otherwise  = Set v l (insert x r)
```

However, depending on your philosophy, your original code might actually be better. With the catch-all in the second, you just defer the weirdness if someone hands you NaN values. This makes it all the more difficult to understand what's going on.

If tend to deliberately *not* complete patterns with “impossible cases” in experimental code: this way I'll at least always get a clear runtime error telling me at which point in the code things go awry. Once the code essentially works and you want to make it production-ready, you can *then* toss in `-Wall` and learn about all spots where you'd better add some explicit handling of pathological behaviour like the one I mentioned.

Comment: I hate seeing `otherwise` in Haskell. Why not advise OP about `compare`?

Comment: @Rhymoid: how would that improve upon an `otherwise` clause here? `compare` itself has a catch-all built in, e.g. `compare (sqrt(-1)) 0 ≡ GT` and `compare 0 (sqrt(-1)) ≡ GT`. Hence my suggestion to _leave the pattern incomplete_ for the time being, and add explicit handling of pathological cases when necessary.

Comment: It would improve its style. I know, it's subjective, but explicitly explaining all cases of `compare` is IMO better than implicitly leaving it to `otherwise` to mean `not the_other_clauses`, if only because the compiler can actually check that what you're writing covers all cases. I don't really care about pathological examples such as IEEE types (which *every language* gets wrong).

Comment: Since `Ord` instances for floating-point representations are badly behaved, I would argue that you should pretty much never use `Ord`-generic functions with them. Anything you use will have to be audited to make sure it does what *you* want, and of course that could change between versions of a dependency.

Comment: @dfeuer never using e.g. `Set Double` would be silly, but you're probably right that you should always eliminate any possibility NaNs before putting floating values in such a set.

Comment: Silly? The instance violates the data structure's expectations. It could behave oddly, and probably does.

Comment: @dfeuer: yes, so what do you propose? There are many applications where you don't get around using floating point. It would be a heck of an overhead to convert anything to e.g. `Rational` before doing `Ord` comparisons, and it wouldn't really solve the problem which is already the `Floating` instance (which you _can't_ migrate to `Rational`, and I don't think any other type would even come close to being practical for those applications).

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I'm just saying you shouldn't expect `Ord`-polymorphic functions and data structures to behave well with floating point representations except under very particular circumstances. For example, using `Double` as a key for `Data.Map` could wreak all sorts of havoc unless you ensure that you never use two keys that are too close to each other. Maybe things work out okay, but I wouldn't expect them to.

Comment: Yeah... Actually the more relevant problem for floats as keys is that you can't rely on mathematically-identical values to compare as equal, since e.g. `(pi + 100) - 80 /= pi + (100 - 80)`. Hence structures like [`IntervalMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/IntervalMap) or something with nearest-neighbour lookup are usually more suitable. The problem is really not the `Ord` instance – that is mostly well-behaved, just [the `Eq` instance doesn't make sense](http://www.paultaylor.eu/ASD/)!